# angular http post never call backend action

Tags: angular, httpclient

i'm trying to perform a http post to my node backend. Todo so i tried this method (triggered by a  button click in a material bottomsheet)

```
 return this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:5000/location/addreview', JSON.stringify({
  username: this.data.username,
  ts: Date.now(),
  userid: this.data.userid,
  rate: this.currentRate,
  message: this.message,
  restId: this.data.locId
})
);
```

Here is my backend:

```
router.post('/addreview', async(req, res) => {
console.log("called")

    const username = req.body.username;
    const userid = req.body.userid;
    const ts = req.body.ts;
    const rate = req.body.rate;
    const message = req.body.message;
    const restaurantId = req.body.restId;
    collection.update(
        { _id: ObjectId(restaurantId) },
        { $push: { reviews: {   username: username,
                                rate: rate,
                                ts: ts,
                                userid: userid,
                                message: message } } }

     )
     res.end("Review saved");
     res.status(200);
}
```

})

the called print is never called so i think the post is never performed

Comment: Http request never get called unless you subscribe to them.

Comment: so i need to add a subscribe block?

Comment: The block you have for the http request returns an observable, wherever you call that function add subscribe() at the end.

Comment: ok thank you got fixed it